# How do I disable fast startup using safe mode?

Tags: windows-10, win10-fast-startup

My laptop turns black, displaying only the cursor as soon as it gets to the point where it shows the Windows login. When I did my research to fix the issue, I saw that disabling fast startup may resolve it (the problem actually occurred the day I enabled fast startup, although I had used it without any problems in the past).

However, I'm not able to login, and when I login using safe mode, the fast startup option isn't there. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this parameter can be changed through the Windows registry editor 10 ( `regedit.exe` ). It is answered by the value of HiberbootEnabled in the registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power`

(if the value is 0, fast loading is disabled, if 1 is enabled).